# this ruby code should return the sum of elements, but only returning the array itself.

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum

```
class Calculator

def initialize
    @array = Array.new
    @total = 0 
end

def push(n)
    @array << n
end

def value
    @total
end

def plus
    size = @array.size
    total =  @array.pop(size) + @array.pop(size-1)
    @array << total
    @total = total
end    
end
```

and the test code is

```
calculator = Calculator.new
calculator.push(2)
calculator.push(3)
calculator.plus
expect(calculator.value).to eq(5)
```

i expected to get '5' from the 'value' method. but it's returning [2,3] which is an array. what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pop with an argument returns an array. Use pop without an argument to get only the number.

```
total =  array + array
```

So, total becomes an array.